# Open drawer from another component in Quasar framework VueJS

Tags: vue.js, frontend, quasar

I'm new with front-end develop and start to use Quasar base on VueJS.

The question is how to open drawer from another component? For now i have  solution to choose a DOM element and call *open()* on it, but i think it is not the best one.

code is **this.$parent.$children[2].$refs.leftDrawer**

component Drawer.Vue content is a drawer tag with ref like:

```
<q-drawer ref="leftDrawer">
....
</q-drawer>
```

And component headerbox.vue content is:

```
<template>
...
<button class="hide-on-drawer-visible" @click="leftDrawer.open()">
...
</template>
<script>
...
    computed: {
      leftDrawer () {
        return (this.$parent.$children[2].$refs.leftDrawer)
      }
...
</script>
```

MainApp Vue content:

```
<template>
 <q-layout>
 <headerbox slot="header"></headerbox>
 <drawer></drawer>
 ...
</q-layout>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  import headerbox from './header.vue'
  import drawer from './drawer.vue'
  ...
  components: {
    headerbox,
    drawer,
    }
  ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use an event on a Message Pump.

Inside your main.js add a line

```
...
window.MessagePump = new Vue()
...
```

then in your component that has the drawer:

```
...
mounted () {
    window.MessagePump.$on(
        'openLeftDrawer',
        () => {
          this.$refs.leftDrawer.open()
        }
    )
}
...
```

And any component that needs to open the drawer

```
...
window.MessagePump.$emit('openLeftDrawer')
...
```

Realistically you could drop the `window.` from the two calls but it's up to your personal preference.